# How to render different view on selecting tabs in ext js4?

Tags: php, extjs, extjs4

1)I have a json file which I want to display in view.

```
{           
    "contents": [
                {
                    "title":'JWorld',
                    "image":'image/e-learning/elearning.png',

                    "subtitle":[
                    {
                        "categories":'Aus',
                    },
                    {
                        "categories":'England',
                    }                
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title":'JIndia',
                    "image":'image/Content/History_of_India.jpg',
                    "subtitle":[
                    {
                        "categories":'History',
                    },
                    {
                        "categories":'India palace',
                    }                
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title":'JMaharastra',
                    "image":'image/Content/Geography.jpg',
                    "subtitle":[
                    {
                        "categories":'History Maharastra',
                    },
                    {
                        "categories":'Maharastra Heros',
                    }                
                    ]
                }
              ]
}
```

2)My view file :--

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.kp.dnycontentcategories.ContentcategoriesView',
{
    extend:'Ext.view.View',
    id:'contentcategoriesViewId',
    alias:'widget.ContentcategoriesView',
    store:'kp.DnycontentcategoriesStore',
    config:
    {
        tpl:'<tpl for="0">'+
                '<div class="main">'+
                '</br>'+
                '<b>{title}</b></br>'+
                '<img src={image} hight="50" width="100"></br>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</tpl>',
        itemSelector:'div.main',
    }
});// End of class
```

3) i am using tab panel and dynamically adding tabs in it using json file.

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.kp.dnycontentcategories.Contentcategories',{
    extend:'Ext.tab.Panel',
    requires:[
              'Balaee.view.kp.dnycontentcategories.ContentcategoriesView','Balaee.view.kp.dnycontentcategories.ContentcategoriesView1'
             ],
    id:'contentcategoriesId',
    alias:'widget.Contentcategories',
    height:500,
    items:[

    ],//end of items square
});// End of login class
```

4) My store file:--

```
Ext.define('Balaee.store.kp.DnycontentcategoriesStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Balaee.model.kp.DnycontentcategoriesModel',
    autoLoad:true,
//    filters: [{
//        property: 'title',
//    }],
    proxy:
    {
        type:'ajax',
        api:
        {
            read:'data/content.json',
            //create: ,
            //update: ,
            //destroy: ,
        },//End of api 
        reader:
        {
            type:'json',
            root:'contents',
            //successProperty: ,
        }//End of reader
    }//End of proxy
});//End
```

5) My Controller file some code
here I am dynamically adding some tabs from json file.And selecting particular tab I want different particular values from json file. But I get same view of first tab. How can I solve this problem.

```
init: function(){
    console.log("inside content controller");
    this.control({
        'Contentcategories':
        {
            render:this.renderFunction,
        }
    });//End of control
},//End of init() function
renderFunction:function(){
    console.log("Inside render function");
    var tabPanel = Ext.getCmp('contentcategoriesId');       // tabpanel  
    var tabPanelView = Ext.getCmp('contentcategoriesViewId');   // tabpanel view

    var storeObject= this.getStore('kp.DnycontentcategoriesStore'); // store
    storeObject.on('load',function(){
        storeObject.each(function(model){
            //tabPanelView.store().filter('title',model.get('title')),
            console.log(model.get('title'));
            console.log(model.get('categories'));
            tabPanel.add({title:model.get('title'),
                            id:model.get('title'),
                            //html:"<image src=model.get('image')>",
                            xtype:'ContentcategoriesView',              
                        }); //End of add function 
        });// End of storeObject function
        tabPanel.setActiveTab(0);
    });
},// End of render function
```

please give me some suggestion.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No. Coding is working but it displays same view when i chaging the tab.

Comment: I think, it is happening because you have passed common kp.DnycontentcategoriesStore to each ContentcategoriesView

Comment: Yes you are right. But I want to group out the data in json file in a diiferent tab.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

You define `ContentcategoriesView` - its a a component you have extended; but you give it an id (`contentcategoriesId`) yet you are creating more than one of these components - it makes no sense as an id has to be unique per component instance.

Then, you attach a store to this view, which means all components will render the same.

If I understand correctly you want each entry in your json to become a different tab.

I would take this direction (code not tested, but should give you a direction):

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.kp.dnycontentcategories.ContentcategoriesView',
{
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel', // Notice it's a panel.
    alias:'widget.ContentcategoriesView',

    config:
    {
        tpl: '<div class="main">' +
             '</br>' +
             '<b>{title}</b></br>' +
             '<img src={image} hight="50" width="100"></br>' +
             '</div>'
        itemSelector:'div.main',
    }
});
```

And then:

```
storeObject.on( 'load',function() {
    storeObject.each( function( model ) {
        tabPanel.add({
            xtype: 'ContentcategoriesView',
            title: model.get( 'title' ),
            id:    model.get( 'title' ),
            data:  model
        }); 
    });
    tabPanel.setActiveTab(0);
});
```

Comment: thanks for give me suggestion. I have been working in your direction.I changed my code but it does not display any image in  a view when I am changing tab. I get a forbidden message on console ->>/Balaee/height=%2250%22 403 (Forbidden)